# NodeJS constructor with literal object in parameter while using v4.2.6

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm using NodeJS v4.2.6 which has a known issue with Block-Scoped declarations not being supported yet. I'm forced to use this version which means I must use the `"use strict";` line to avoid this error:

```
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet sup
ported outside strict mode
```

Which works fine, however, I've just downloaded an NPM with the following syntax that looks like nothing I've seen before:

```
const request = require('request');
const qs = require('querystring');
const _ = require('underscore');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const Beautifier = require('./beautifier.js');
const assert = require('assert')

class MyClassTest {

    constructor({ key, secret, recvWindow, timeout, disableBeautification }) {
        this.key = key;
        this.secret = secret;
        this.recvWindow = recvWindow;
        this.timeout = timeout || 15000;
        this.disableBeautification = disableBeautification;

        this._beautifier = new Beautifier();
        this._baseUrl = `https://www.thisisatestlol.com/`;
    }
}
```

I've never seen an object, or curly braces at the parameters area on a function. What is this?

After seeing the Block-scoped declaration error I talked before, I added the "use strict"; line which did clear out the message but now shows a different one.

```
    constructor({ key, secret, recvWindow, timeout, disableBeautification }) {
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I've never dealt with this, how can I fix it and have my NPM run smoothly?

I added the Block-scoped declarations error because I feel like it has to do with it, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: An ES6 feature: ["Object destructuring for function parameters"](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/).  It assigns those property names in the passed-in object to a function argument with the same name as the property name.  So, `key` is like `arguments[0].key` and `secret` is like `arguments[0].secret` and so on.  Just saves some typing.

Comment: how can you fix this ? . update nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an ES6 feature: ["Object destructuring for function parameters"](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/).

It assigns those property names in the passed-in object to a function argument with the same name as the property name.  So, `key` is like `arguments[0].key` and `secret` is like `arguments[0].secret` and so on.  Just saves some typing.

So, this:

```
constructor({ key, secret, recvWindow, timeout, disableBeautification }) {
   this.key = key;
   // ...
}
```

works like this:

```
constructor(obj) {
   let key = obj.key;
   let secret = obj.secret;
   let recvWindow = obj.key;
   let timeout = obj.timeout;
   let disableBeautification = obj.disableBeautification;

   this.key = key;
   // ...
}
```

Article references:

[Destructing objects as function parameters in ES6](https://simonsmith.io/destructuring-objects-as-function-parameters-in-es6/)

[Use destructuring in function parameters](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/use-destructuring-in-function-parameters/)

---

> I've never dealt with this, how can I fix it and have my NPM run smoothly?

That object destructing for function parameters ES6 feature is not supported in node.js until node v6 so if you can't upgrade your node version past node v4, then you will have to edit the code to be like this:

```
constructor(obj) {
   var key = obj.key;
   var secret = obj.secret;
   var recvWindow = obj.key;
   var timeout = obj.timeout;
   var disableBeautification = obj.disableBeautification;

   this.key = key;
   // ...
}
```

Or use a transpiler that supports ES6 features such as babeljs and transpile that module into ES5 code.

> I added the Block-scoped declarations error because I feel like it has to do with it, maybe I'm wrong.

They are separate ES6 features.  The v4 version of node you are on was in the midst of implementing support for block scoped `let` so you could use it in `strict` mode only or with a command line option.

Now that you know what these features are called, you can look them up in this table: http://node.green/ to see what version of node.js supports what.